# Wordpress: How to enter the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I read that the **$post** object has to be accessed in **the loop**.
Currently the following code logs nothing.

```
    global $post;      
    error_log(print_r($post, true));
```

I think this is because I'm not in the loop.
What are ways to access this loop then? Can we access it via some hook or filter?

Comment: The loops is a basic part of WP Development: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: Every page or post is part of "the loop" (although, for a single post, it's a loop of 1 post). Where are you trying to use this code? If you've hooked into an action it might be that particular action is being run before the loop has been generated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, you can use the following hook to enter the loop:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'myfunction');

function myfunction() {

    global $post;
    error_log(print_r($post, true));   // on this hook $posts should log

}
```

All the code inside `myfunction` is guaranteed to be in the loop